# Is it correct to say "the mug is on the hole" or "the mug is on the ground" in this case?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-request, phrase-choice

[image]

There is a hole and a mug, the diameter of the mug is bigger than the hole. The mug blocked the hole as shown in the picture.

Is it correct to say "**the mug is on the hole**" or "**the mug is on the ground**" in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both would be correct depending on what you wanted to convey.

I would probably say, "The mug covers the hole."